# How to set tomorrow leave details of employee -react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here i got all absent emloyee details from loopback and put into the array (data[]).code below

```
 getAbsentDet() {
    this.props.actions.getAbsentDetails().then(() => {
      if (!this.props.common.getAbsentDetailsPending) {


        this.setState({ data: this.props.common.absDetails.emp  });
      }
    });
  }
```

Here show only employee details  who are leave today.how to do who are leave tomorrow? .my code is below...

```
render() {
    return (
      <div className="common-right-coll-bar" id="rightMenu">

        <Sider style={{ overflow: 'auto', height: '100vh', width: 300, right: 0, backgroundColor: '#f5f5f5', position: 'fixed', color: '#036cd2' }}>
          {/* <Sider style={{ height: 150, width: 300, backgroundColor: '#fff', }}> */}

          {this.state.data.length !== 0?<ul style={{ marginTop: 30 }}>
          <h1> Absent Today</h1>  
            {this.state.data.map(data =>
                (  
                  <li key={data .id} style={{ padding: 5, margin: 5, marginLeft: 10 }}>
                    <div> 
                    <span>
                      <Badge><Avatar style={{ color: '#ffffff', borderStyle: 'solid', borderWidth: 2 }} size="large" src={`./${data.profile_img}`} /></Badge>
                    </span>
                    <span style={{ marginLeft: 10, color: '#036cd2' }}>
                      {data.f_name} {data.l_name}
                    </span>

                  </div>
                  </li>)
              )}

            <div className="check" id="rightMenu" ref="check" style={{ padding: 5 }}>
            </div>

          </ul> : <div style={{ marginTop: 100, marginLeft: 10, fontSize: 30, borderStyle: 'solid', borderColor: 'black', textAlign: 'center', color: 'lightGray' }}>No one is absent today </div>}

        </Sider>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This is my server code (loopback).Here show only employee details  who are leave today.how to do who are leave tomorrow?

```
LeaveDetails.tomo_absentEmp = function(cb) {
    var log = bunyan.createLogger({
      name: 'leaveServer-logger', streams: [
        {
          level: 'info',
          path: './log/info/log_' + moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD').toString() + '.log',
        },
        {
          level: 'error',
          path: './log/error/log_' + moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD').toString() + '.log',
        }],
      serializers: { err: bunyan.stdSerializers.err },
    });
    console.log('Request for the employee absent sheet');
    log.info({
      type: 'info', time: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm').toString(),
      model: 'leave-details',
      method: 'tomo_absentEmp',
    }, 'request for absent employee');

    let filter = { where: { leave_status: 3 }, fields: ['user_id', 'leave_start_time', 'leave_end_time','number_of_days']};
    LeaveDetails.find(filter, function(err, leaves) {
      var returnArray = [];
      var returnEle;
      var employee = app.models.employee;
      var ids = [];
      async.eachOf(leaves, function(leave, index, acb) {
        var leaveStart = moment(leave.leave_start_time).startOf('day');
        var leaveEnd = moment(leave.leave_end_time).endOf('day');
        var now = moment();


        if (now.isBetween(leaveStart, leaveEnd) && !ids.includes(leave.user_id)) {
          ids.push(leave.user_id);
          employee.findById(leave.user_id, {fields: ['f_name', 'l_name', 'profile_img', 'id']}, function(err, tomoabsemp) {
            returnEle = {};
            returnEle['id'] = tomoabsemp.id;
            returnEle['f_name'] = tomoabsemp.f_name;
            returnEle['l_name'] = tomoabsemp.l_name;
            returnEle['profile_img'] = tomoabsemp.profile_img;
            returnEle['leave_start_time'] = leaveStart;
            returnEle['leave_end_time'] =leaveEnd;
            returnEle['number_of_days'] =leave.number_of_days;

            returnArray.push(returnEle);
            return acb(null);
          });
        }        else {
          return acb(null);
        }
      },
       function(err) {
         if (err) {
           return cb(null, err);
           log.error({
             type: 'error', time: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm').toString(),
             model: 'leave-details',
             method: 'tomo_absentEmp',
           }, 'absent employee responce failed');
         } else {
           console.log('send the absent employee details successfuly');
           log.info({
             type: 'success',
             model: 'leave-details',
             method: 'tomo_absentEmp',
           }, 'absent employee responce successfull');

           return cb(null, returnArray);
         }
       }
    );

    });
  };
```

Comment: Um, get the data of tomorrow from the server with a different `http` call?

Comment: @TomasEglinskas sir i updated my cod above plz look at